# How to access a dictionary inside a function?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to find maximum value of `freq`.

```
def frequency_map(text, k):
  n = len(text)
  freq = {}
  for i in range(n-k+1):
      pattern = text[i:i+k]
      if not pattern in freq:
        freq[pattern] = 1
      else:
        freq[pattern] += 1
  return freq 


text = 'massachusettsassemblymass'
k = 3

print(frequency_map(text, k))
print(max(freq.values()))
```

It gives a `NameError. name 'freq' is not defined`.
How to go about it? All keys with maximums needed to be found.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by assigning the value to a variable:

```
freq = frequency_map(text, k)
```

You can then find the max value by changing which function max uses to determine "maximality" with `key=func`:

```
m = max(freq.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Then you can filter the dictionary for all values matching that maximum by passing the appropriate predicate:

```
all_max = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] == m[1], freq.items()))
```

Returns:

```
{'ass': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after `k = 3` Write `temp = frequency_map(text, k)` Then use your `max(freq.values())` on `temp` instead of `freq`.

When you call that function it returns a list that you print in your first `print` statement. But after that you are not storing the list anywhere so the program is just going to throw it away when try to use it in your second print statement the program won't find it and it will give you an error.

That's way you need to store that list in order to use it again.

Comment: No problem. Please mark the question as solved by pressing the solved button on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
def frequency_map(text, k):
    n = len(text)
    freq = {}
    for i in range(n - k + 1):
        pattern = text[i:i + k]
        if not pattern in freq:
            freq[pattern] = 1
        else:
            freq[pattern] += 1
    return freq

text = 'massachusettsassemblymass'
k = 3

frequencies = frequency_map(text, k)
print(frequencies)
highest_freq = (max(frequencies.values()))
print({k: v for k, v in frequencies.items() if v == highest_freq})
```